# How to increment a record in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase record "searches: 0" for each user. On some event, I'd like to add 1 to what the current count is. I've gotten this far, but for some reason, it's not working:

```
du.fbAddSearchCount = function() {
    var usr = new Firebase(firebase_url + "/users/" + user_uid);

    usr.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        user = snapshot.val();

       var usersRef = ref.child("users");

       var fbUser = usersRef.child(user_uid);
       fbUser.update( {
           searches: user.searches + 1
       });
    }
}
```

Any help to get this working?

Thank you.

Comment: what's user.searches?

Comment: That would be the value that is currently in the user's "searches" record in fire base. For example, if it's 5, I'd like this script to update that to read 6.

Comment: So what is not working? Gotta give some more details. Does it update the record at all but not with the new number?

Comment: Seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31361993/how-to-count-child-elements-in-angularfire/31362510#31362510

Comment: What event is supposed to trigger the incrementing of searches count?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's a new method `ServerValue.increment()`in firebase JavaScript SDK v7.14.0

It's better for performance and cheaper since no round trip is required.

See [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js)

> Added ServerValue.increment() to support atomic field value increments without transactions.

API Docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue)

Usage example:

```
firebase.database()
    .ref('users')
    .child(user_uid)
    .child('searches')
    .set(firebase.database.ServerValue.increment(1))
```

Or you can decrement, just put `-1` as function arg like so:

```
firebase.database()
    .ref('users')
    .child(user_uid)
    .child('searches')
    .set(firebase.database.ServerValue.increment(-1))
```

Comment: Great update Oleg. There is now indeed also an `increment` operation for the Realtime Database, which performs significantly better than using a transaction (see my test [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61536203/how-quickly-can-you-atomically-increment-a-value-on-the-firebase-realtime-databa)).

Answer (score 21):

You can use transaction

```
var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref('users').child(user_uid).child('searches');

databaseRef.transaction(function(searches) {
  if (searches) {
    searches = searches + 1;
  }
  return searches;
});
```

Comment: Your code will not work when `searches = 0`. You can instead do this: `return (searches || 0) + 1;`

Answer (score 6):

For the **Realtime Database** the use of `transaction` seems to be the best way to do it. See [the answer from Sunday G Akinsete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38831634/4358185)

From his answer and the related comments:

```
firebase
    .database()
    .ref('users')
    .child(user_uid)
    .child('searches')
    .transaction(function(searches) {
        return (searches || 0) + 1
    })
```

For the **Firestore Database** you can use the [Firebase Sentinel values](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue) to increment/decrement a value that without having to fetch it first

Increment

```
firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection('users')
    .doc('some-user')
    .update({ 
         valueToIncrement: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1) 
    })
```

Decrement

```
firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection('users')
    .doc('some-user')
    .update({ 
        valueToDecrement: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1) 
    })
```

[Documentation Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#static-increment)

Comment: Nice, but the original question seems to be using Realtime Database instead of Firestore.

Comment: Ah yes I didn't notice, I updated the answer to specify that's for Firestore only. Thank you !

Answer (score 5):

For the **Realtime Database**, using [`increment()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#increment) works well for this - here's a client-side JS example that uses the newer ESM syntax

```
import { getDatabase, ref, set, increment } from  "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.3/firebase-database.js";


// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseConfig = { ...};
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


const writeFavNameData = name => {
    const db = getDatabase();
    const favRef = ref(db, 'favorites/' + name);
    set(favRef, {
            name,
            likes: increment(1)
    });
};

writeFavNameData("Petunia"); // `likes` is initialized at 1
writeFavNameData("Petunia"); // `likes` is now 2
```

Comment: Thanks for showing the Firebase 9 syntax. I couldn't find any examples in the docs for how to use increment like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
ref.transection(function(queue_length) {
    if(queue_length|| (queue_length === 0))
    {
        queue_length++; 
    }
    return queue_length;

})
```

You can use like this ;)

Comment: provide an explanation to your answer

Comment: What environment COMPILES javascript?

Answer (score 0):

```
database.ref("users").child("user_uid").transaction((user) => {
    if (user) {
        user.searches = actives.searches + 1;
    }
    return user;
});
```

It works for you.
I did that '.child('searches')' but It doesn't work.(nothing changed).