# Add/Increment Value - Firebase Database w/ Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Xcode and I want to know how to add/increment value instead of set value. Appreciate your help in advance.

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class Feedback1Controller: UIViewController {

    var ref: DatabaseReference?

    @IBAction func Button3(_ sender: Any){
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref?.child("FavBooth").child("Booth A").setValue(1)
    }
```

[Image of my Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6m5Kq.png)

Comment: Use transactions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions

Comment: see answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38831634/1014164