# Firebase database several updates of the same value at the same time

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

There is a certain **int** value in the realtime database. I modify it using two different Firebase functions. Suppose now it is 500 and both of these functions have been called. One should add **100** to the value, the other - **20**. I get the current value from the database (**500**) in each function and add the corresponding value to it, then write the new value to the database. If I understand correctly, then I will lose one of the values ​​and in the database I will have the value that was last recorded (**600** or **520**). How can this be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing requires that you use a transaction, or the recently added `increment()` operation.

From Cloud Functions you'll be using the Firebase Admin SDK for Node, where this can be as simple as:

```
ref.set(firebase.database.ServerValue.increment(100));
```

And

```
ref.set(firebase.database.ServerValue.increment(-20));
```

Also see my answer comparing the performance of both operations: [How quickly can you atomically increment a value on the Firebase Realtime Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61536203/how-quickly-can-you-atomically-increment-a-value-on-the-firebase-realtime-databa/61536204#61536204)