# Optimal Firebase Cloud Function to be called everytime a child is added

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I would like a function to get executed everytime a new user is added to a matchmaking object, to increase the number of matchmaking users.

```
exports.onCreateMatchmakingUser = functions.database.ref('/matchmaking/{$uid}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const currentMatchmakingAmount = snapshot.ref.parent.child('matchmakingAmount').val();
    return snapshot.ref.parent.update({matchmakingAmount: currentMatchmakingAmount+1});
});
```

I don't want to fetch the whole matchmaking object and then fetch the number, I just want the matchmakingAmount. Does `snapshot.ref.parent` make this a problem (does it fetch the whole matchmaking object, or just the reference to it without downloading its data)? And if it does, how can I solve this problem and write another function that just updates the number without unnecessary downloads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `snapshot.ref.parent.child('matchmakingAmount')` in your code doesn't read anything from the database. Instead, it merely sets up a reference to the `matchmakingAmount` in the database. You'll still need to explicitly read it with `once("value")`:

```
let amountRef = snapshot.ref.parent.child('matchmakingAmount');
return amountRef.once("value").then((amount) => {
  let currentMatchmakingAmount = amount.val();
  return amountRef.set(currentMatchmakingAmount+1});
});
```

---

Luckily there is nowadays a simpler way to do this, as Firebase has a built-in `increment` operator. With that, the above boils down to:

```
let amountRef = snapshot.ref.parent.child('matchmakingAmount');
amountRef.set(admin.database.ServerValue.increment(1));
```

This approach also solves the race condition that exists in your approach: if two people trigger the Cloud Function at almost the same time, the two writes may get into each other's way. By using a server-side `increment` that won't happen.

Also see:

- [How quickly can you atomically increment a value on the Firebase Realtime Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61536203/how-quickly-can-you-atomically-increment-a-value-on-the-firebase-realtime-databa)

Comment: When implementing the second bit of code you've written, should I also return amountRef.set(admin.database.ServerValue.increment(1)); since set returns a promise?

Comment: Yup. Since the write is asynchronous, you want to Cloud Function to remain alive until it completes and for that you need to return the promise to the container.