# How to get a "Sequence" or counters like structure in firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am moving from sql to nosql database,as a part of it I am working on a flutter project where I am implementing a sequence like structure as below.

```
  static Future<int> get nextId async {
    return database.get().then((snapshot) {
      return snapshot.value;
    }).then((value) {
      database.set(value + 1);
      return value + 1;
    });
  }
```

It works, each time i am using nextID it increments in the database. My question is that is it possible when two different users happens to get the same value on invoking nextId.

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to prevent multiple users from modifying the same value in conflicting ways, you'll want to [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions).

In this case, since you seem to be simply incrementing a value, you may also be helped by using the [atomic increment](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#atomic_server-side_increments) operation which is significantly faster as I showed in: [How quickly can you atomically increment a value on the Firebase Realtime Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61536203)